# error using fwrite() to write data structure in c

Tags: c, cs50, fread

Please i'm trying to use fwrite to write a data structure to a .txt file after running it the output of the file is ��t��t��t��t��t��t
this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* regnum;
    int age;
}
student;

int main()
{
    char *studentName = get_string("What's your name: ");
    char *studentReg = get_string("Input your Registeration Number: ");
    int age = get_int("How old are you: ");

    student newStudent = {studentName, studentReg, age};

    FILE *studentinfo = fopen("Student's_Information.txt", "w");
    if (studentinfo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file");
    }
    fwrite(&newStudent, sizeof(student), 1, studentinfo);
    fclose(studentinfo);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `fwrite` to write to a text file? Your struct contains pointers, so you can't just write it to the file anyway, you need to serialize the data the pointers point to. An alternative would be to use fixed size char arrays in the struct. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `fwrite` is very literal. Rather than writing the data at a pointer, it writes the pointer. That's typically not all that useful because what the pointer points at is usually gone when you reload the pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 what do you suggest I do

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried it, it gives me same output

Comment: I'm not sure what "it" refers to, but since I can't see "it" I can't comment. Again, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: [Serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). For a string, what I generally do is write out the length of the string in an integer of known [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and follow it with the characters in the string.